# What program is using Ctrl+Shift+2 in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I want to find the GNOME configuration item of the program (built into GNOME or something installed into it) is consuming <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> such that it is not "seen" by other X programs such as Firefox.

I have tried this experiment on two different laptops, of different manufacturers, one running GNOME under Ubuntu 14.10 and the other running under Debian Testing. However, this does work on my desktop machine that is not using GNOME at all (runs StumpWM):

1. Run the `xev` program.
2. Move your mouse cursor into the xev window.
3. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
4. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
5. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

Notice that you see no output for when you press or release the "2" above, but you do see output for "1" and "3".

Executing:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i -e shift
```

Results in nothing specifically for "2":

```
org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-recording ['<Control><Shift><Alt>r']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot '<Shift>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot-clip '<Ctrl><Shift>Print'
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Up']
```

Does anyone know what is consuming that key binding? Any ideas on how to debug this further, ideally through specially crafted Google search versus a ritual involving massive download, and recursive grepping through, GNOME source code?

Comment: xev reports any X input event, no matter if it is caught by some hotkey listener or not. May your "2" just be broken?

Comment: The "2" key works when it is not modified with CTRL or SHIFT.